# Xcode 7.1.1 Crashing When Changing Attributes in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I am using Xcode 7.1.1 on OS 10.11.1. When I make changes to fonts, background colors, etc. in interface builder it crashes. I can make one change then when I make another one it will crash so I've been having to save after each change then open the project again after the crash and make another change then repeat the process. Does anyone know of a fix or workaround for this?

Comment: I'm not having that problem with the same OS and Xcode. I have build 7B91b, is yours the same?

Comment: Version 7.1.1 build 7B1005

Comment: I've found others with the same issue, but no fix. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23653